# Can we implement autoshare in facebook using xcode?

Tags: iphone

I am doing an iphone application in which i need to provide autoshare option to share automatically the text in an UIView in facebook when we click save button. i will save the facebook username and password of the user in datbase and retrived and want to assign for facebook and password without FBDialog... is it possible? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Storing a fb user / pass combo is probably out of the question. Your best option is to use the Facebook iOS SDK and then ask for offline_access & publish_stream as part of your permissions when you authenticate the user. This way you will be able to access the users data at any time and post to their wall at any time.

The method you seek to implement IS possible, just frowned upon and somewhat unethical.

Hope this helps.